# SUBSTR with INSTR occurrence

Tags: oracle, substring

I have a string with delimiter "##GS##" like this "##GS##ABC##GS##DEF##GS##GHI##GS##",

the length of value in between delimeter is vary, the query is to retrieve value in between 3rd and 4th delimeter, in this case GHI.

The script below works, anyway if I can improve without hardcoding with '-16'?

`SELECT SUBSTR('##GS##ABC##GS##DEF##GS##GHI##GS##',
INSTR('##GS##ABC##GS##DEF##GS##GHI##GS##', '##GS##', 1, 3)+6,INSTR('##GS##ABC##GS##DEF##GS##GHI##GS##', '##GS##', 1, 3)-16)AS CUS_REF_ID FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? The desired value is the 6th "word":

```
SQL> with test as (select '##GS##ABC##GS##DEF##GS##GHI##GS##' col from dual)
  2    select regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 6) result
  3  from test;

RES
---
GHI

SQL>
```

Comment: great..what does it mean '\w+' here? can i assign this entire statement to a string variable in PL SQL?

Comment: "\w" is a "word" (alphanumerics plus underscore); "+" means "take all of them, until there's no more (i.e. up to the first # sign). No problem in assigning it to a variable, such as `my_var := regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 6);`